# Should we have Multiple vue apps or a single app per page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

We currently have a large site with a primarily razor/mvc front end.

Over the last couple of years we’ve been sprinkling vue on top but so far it’s been as a separate vue app each time. So a page might have 3-5 vue apps on it eg two different modals, a form, a little widget in the header.

We’ve had some more complex apps where we’ve used pinia to manage state between multiple sub components but not between apps.

We’re getting to the point where vue us starting to gain momentum and multiple key pages are moving to full vue.

**My question: is there any downside to having multiple vue instances/apps on a page, I know we could define the pinia store once and pass it into the apps to let them share the store or should we be looking to have one app per page or eventually making parts of the site a spa**

Is there a “best practice”?

We’re leaning more towards the multiple app route for no real reason.

Comment: The question asks for opinions, which isn't allowed on SO. "I know we could define the pinia store once " - you need to know what you're doing at this point because the problem with multiple apps is that they still need to be developed and bundled together in order to use the same global store instance (pinia or else). You can use teleports within a single app and make it look like multiple apps that don't have a common parent in DOM

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to mount different components into any DOM nodes with the only one app instance per page (this will allow to have one Vue app for the whole page) you could use a technique I've described in:

[Mounting components individually without a root like #app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76460347/mounting-components-individually-without-a-root-like-app/76460743#76460743)

(the source code is provided)

The other way to go is to use Web Components with Vue:

https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html

ALSO: if you still use multiple Vue apps per page, nothing stops you from using shared ES modules and even Pinia stores between the apps.

I would say that probably optimally you would go with this last option to avoid heavy refactoring and thus losing time for delivering actual features.